# Entering text data after a blank space from previous paragraph

Tags: python

I have a myplants.txt file displayed below:

```
Caladium White Christmas
2020-03-07 10:10:20
Partial sun to bright full shade
Direct sun might burn Leaves
Water regularly and never allow soil to dry out
Soil must be loose and well draining

Sansevieria Trifasciata (Snake Plant)
2020-05-22 09:56:49
Full shade to full sun
Well-draining soil
Water only when top 1 inch of soil is dry
Propagate by cuttings
1
2
3
chilli
2020-08-21, 03:20:43
hot
```

If you notice, the chilli data is entered 3 blank spaces away from the previous Sansevieria Trifasciata (Snake Plant) paragraph. How to ensure that what the user inputs will have data displayed exactly one blank space away from the previous paragraph?

Below is my attached code:

```
print("Welcome to myplants dictionary database!")


print("Opening the file...")
target = open('myplants.txt', 'a')
# can open the file to w- write, read and write or append
print("Now I'm going to ask you for the details.")

target.write("\n")
line1 = input("What is the new plant name? ")
target.write("\n")
target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")

from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
target.write(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S"))
date_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S")
print("Latest revision time is: ",date_time)


target.write("\n")
line3 = input("What is the description of the plant? ")
target.write(line3)

print("I'm going to write these to the file.")

target.close()
print("And finally, we close it.")
```

Comment: I'm unclear. Are you asking how to remove extra blank lines? Or how to keep "chili" as the last item?

Comment: Does the file already include too many blank lines, or are you adding them yourself?

Comment: The script above works just that sometimes it will automatically indent 3 to 4 blank space after the sentence "Propogate by cuttings. Where I just want to indent 1 blank space after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make "chilli" and the date not appear in the same line you should concatenate the line1 variable and a "\n" string instead of having a separate write function that writes a new line. That's what caused it to appear spaced out like that.

```
print("Welcome to myplants dictionary database!")


print("Opening the file...")
target = open('myplants.txt', 'a')
# can open the file to w- write, read and write or append
print("Now I'm going to ask you for the details.")

target.write("\n\n")
line1 = input("What is the new plant name? ")
target.write(line1 + '\n')

from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
target.write(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S"))
date_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S")
print("Latest revision time is: ",date_time)


target.write("\n")
line3 = input("What is the description of the plant? ")
target.write(line3)

print("I'm going to write these to the file.")
target.close()
print("And finally, we close it.")
```

Comment: Thank you. It works for a quite an extent. But sometimes when I put cursor in the text file elsewhere, it may fail. :)